# 'Once Only Controller' is not working and throwing the error 'ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.StackOverflowError'

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

**Once Only Controller** is not working and throwing this **error:**

`ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Looks like '**Once Only Controller**' is not working with '**Stepping Thread Group**' and my test plan looks like as below. if remove '**Once Only Controller**' then my test plan works fine.

**My Test Plan looks like:**

```
-Stepping Thread Group  
--HTTP Request Defaults  
---HTTP Cookie Manager  
----Recording Controller  
-----Once Only Controller  
------HTTP Request
```

**JMeter Throws the below ERROR:**

```
2016/06/23 12:04:14 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:362)
    at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:462)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.get(LinkedHashMap.java:301)
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.get(Collections.java:2037)
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getProperty(AbstractTestElement.java:184)
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsBoolean(AbstractTestElement.java:239)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager.getClearEachIteration(CookieManager.java:160)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager.testIterationStart(CookieManager.java:445)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyTestListeners(JMeterThread.java:809)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$IterationListener.iterationStart(JMeterThread.java:891)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:405)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:397)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:158)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)
    at 
.
.
.
.
.
.
.org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.nextIsNull(LoopController.java:151)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:171)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:225)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:176)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.nextIsNull(LoopController.java:151)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:171)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:225)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:176)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.nextIsNull(LoopController.java:151)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:171)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:225)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:176)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.nextIsNull(LoopController.java:151)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:171)
```